# Is it haraam to draw an eye?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

Is it haraam to draw an eye? Just an eye and no face? 
Answers on the internet are varying. If yes, why? I tried searching on the internet but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Do not make what is halal, into something haram.
Why would drawing an eye be haram? You already know anything you create cannot rival what Allah created, but are merely expressing creativity and/or honing skill that Allah honed for you. Perhaps if you were drawing naked bodies with the intention of lusting over them, or drawing excessively at the cost of your daily obligations, or with the intention of using the eye as a talisman against the "evil eye" it would not be so permissible. But drawing sn eye, or people, or nature in itself is relatively harmless.

Comment: Always provide reference from Qur'an or Hadith

Comment: This dosnt need reference. The words "halal" and "haram" are thrown around so easily these days without their proper implications. You cant associate everything with halal or haram. Drawing an eye has nothing to do with illegality in the religion.